# str() functions and return str object from int object

Tags: python

The python documentation explains the [**str()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function.
But what do mean by 
"Return a string version of object."

if i do this

```
i=1
j=str(i)
```

function **str()** make copy of **int** object **i** and return **str** object as presentation?

Comment: str() will change the int 1 to str "1" so when you print type(i) it will be int and type(j) it will be str

Comment: I understand this, but I would like to know what happens to the **int** object after the **str()** function is applied, how **int** object is represent in the **str** object

Comment: the int object remains as int, j (in your code) takes the value of str version of i. that means type of j is str and type of i is int because it's value is always 1 and was never modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in the sense that str() returns an object, it doesn't directly copy it into a new variable.

Yes in the sense that your code makes a variable named j and stores i converted to a string in it ("copy").

"Return" means a function changes to become a value. `str(1)` returned "1" (string) and you assigned it (with `=`) to j, so j is "1".

Comment: If **str(1)** returned "1" (string) this means that **str()** return **string** object obtained from **int** object?

Comment: Yes, it returns

Answer (score 1):

The str() method returns the string representation of a given object.

```
i=1
j=str(i)
```

This means that j is a string representation of i (j is a copy of a but as string)

For the encoding, it is used with byte objects which are defined by the bytes() method.

```
# declare a byte object
b = bytes('pythön', encoding='utf-8')
# convert a utf-8 byte object to ascii with errors ignored
print(str(b, encoding='ascii', errors='ignore'))

# convert a utf-8 byte object to ascii with strict error
print(str(b, encoding='ascii', errors='strict'))
```

Output :

```
pythn
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: "j is a copy of a but as string" **j** is a string object?